# Why Server Liferay 7.x is unable to start?

Tags: java, configuration, liferay

When I start Server Liferay for the first time everything goes well. But when I stop the server and then I try to start it again, I get the following error:

> [ServiceProxyFactory:265] Service
>   "com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.SingleVMPool" is unavaiable in 60000
>   milliseconds while setting field "_singleVMPool" for class
>   "com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.SingleVMPoolUtil", will retry...

I have a workaround: delete the `%LIFERAY_HOME%\osgi\state` folder content and start the server.

How may I solve this issue? Could it be a configuration issue?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - I'd suggest you carry this question over to the Liferay forums, because it's quite off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you using a java agent to monitor the environ?  I've seen that agents not properly registered can cause startup problems.

Comment: @OlafKock thank you. I think you're right. I will post it in the liferay forums.

Comment: @dnebing I have a java agent running, but I think it's correctly configured. Could you explain me what you think?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a java agent with Liferay but haven't configured it completely, you can end up with ClassNotFoundExceptions and, in some cases, failures starting the SingleVMPools.

The fix is pretty easy, though, and is covered here: https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-ce-7-x-liferay-dxp-7-x-java-agents

Comment: sounds interesting. Let me check this solution